# Force Graphviz to complain for duplicate nodes

Tags: graphviz

I just noticed that duplicate node names (even if labeled uniquely) get processed without complaint by Graphviz. For example, consider the following simple graph as rendered (with circo) in the image below:

```
graph { 
      a [label="a1"]
      a [label="a2"]
      b
      c
      d
      e
      a -- b; 
      b -- c; 
      a -- c; 
      d -- c; 
      e -- c; 
      e -- a; 
}
```

[image: A simple graph with two duplicate nodes a]

I want the above graph to have two nodes: a1 and a2. So I know I should instantiate them with unique names (different than what I did above). But in a large graph, I may not notice that I mistakenly instantiated two different nodes with identical names. So if I do something like this, I'd like to force Graphviz to complain about it or bring it to my attention somehow, maybe with a warning or an error message.

How do I accomplish that?

Comment: it is perfectly legal for a node to appear multiple times in a dot file. even if you think so, there is no explicit node creation, nodes are created implicitly on their first appearance. there is no way to distinguish 'wanted' creations from 'unwanted' ones. also, if you are afraid of wrongly named nodes, how would you find nodes that have wrong name and no collision?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the `graphviz` programs silently merge nodes with duplicate names and I cannot find any way to have them produce a warning when they do that. Since we only have to find the cases where nodes are declared by themselves, however, rather than nodes that are implicitly declared when an edge is declared (in which case duplication is normal and expected), we just have to find all the node names and identify the duplicates.

If no more than one node is ever declared on a line, this could be done with the following script:

```
#!/bin/sh
sed -n 's/^[\t ][\t ]*\([_a-zA-Z][_a-zA-Z0-9]*\) *\(\[.*\)*;*$/\1/ p' | \
sort | uniq -c | awk '$$1>1'
```

If we call this script `findDupNodes`, we can run it as follows:

```
$ findDupNodes <duplicates.gv
      2 a
```

The script finds node names that are either declared by themselves or with a list of attributes that starts with `[`, sorts them, counts how many times each is declared (with `uniq -c`) and filters out the ones that are declared only once.

Multiple nodes can be declared on a single line (e.g. `a; b; c; d;`) but this script does not handle that case, or (probably) some other cases -- most of which would probably require a full-blown `xdot` language parser.

Nevertheless, this script should find many of the duplicate node names that might find their way into hand-written `graphviz` scripts.

Comment: I would never declare more than one node on a line, so this script will work wonderfully for me. Thanks very much!